# Can't chance bootstrap navbar color with my own css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I have looked at other solutions and implemented my own to css to change the color of my bootstrap navbar but it remains as the original color. I also can't see anywhere in the navbar class where the color is defined as I've seen in the past with bootstrap.

Also, when I import, the navbar options don't fit on my home screen. Forgive me if this question is a simple fix as this is my first time using stack overflow and interacting with community!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Paluma Sound</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    

  </head>
  <body>
    
    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo" class="center">
      <source src="Videos/asweareFINAL!!.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <!-- Optional: some overlay text to describe the video -->
    <script src="" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `!important` when using bootstrap to change thigs like that. So for example add this to your CSS:

```
.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: ok, i actually got it to work by changing navbar-inverse to nav-bar custom. Can anyone help identify why the navbar as a whole won't fit within the top of the web page?

Comment: @iangoodman that's becaue you have a video before your nav bar.  switch the order of them in your HTML like this: https://jsfiddle.net/2efhrsyt/

Comment: hm, i switched it around  and it still appears to be doing it. Like it looks normal on the page and then when I hit the dropdown button on the hamburger menu it shows me all of the hidden nav items for a brief moment